# Request permission to use offline persistence (web) with Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a major update to my app and I wanted to take advantage of Firestore's offline persistence (web) as a caching layer (as described in this recent Firebase video: https://youtu.be/iQOTjUko9WM ).

I have a tester who swears she has no security-related extensions installed. Or even any sort of third-party app meant to 'harden' a device.

But my app's offline persistence does not work for her... and only her, out of about 20 testers.

In Chrome she sees a message "**Audit usage of navigator.useragent navigator.appversion and navigator.platform**" in her console (but hasn't toggled the triangle to see if there is more info).

In Edge she sees "**tracking prevention blocked access to storage for...**" and that is followed by "FirebaseError: Failed to get document from cache..."

Is there some sort of permission request needed in some cases? Or some sort of 'defensive' check I need to add before using `getDocFromCache()`?

I really want to use offline persistence as a cache to prevent unnecessary reads as the user moves around in my app. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like they've got strict tracking prevention mode enabled in Edge (and the equivalent in Chrome).

Have them check (for Edge) Privacy, search, and services -> Tracking Prevention. If it is set to Strict move back to Balanced, also check for Blocked trackers and/or allow an Exception.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will ask her to check this. Appreciate the quick response.

Comment: Unfortunately her browser was already in Balanced mode with block tracking not on my site. ;/